# Credentials based on parameter's environment selection

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a pipeline script that has a choices parameter based on environment. For example:

```
parameters {
    choice(choices: 'Development\nStaging\nProduction', description: 
    "Select an environment to run tests against.", name: 'Environment')
}
```

Based on this selection, I would like to load several variables, denoted by environment, but I'm having a hard time selecting the 'parameterized credentials'. I am trying to do somethign like this:

```
stage("Run tests") {
  environment {
    ENV="${params.Environment}"
    DBPASS=credentials("$ENV:dbpass") # <-- this doesn't work!
    MQPASS=credentials("$ENV:mqpass")
    ...
    ...
    5 more credentials here based on environment
    }
}
```

Where the credentials basically follow an "$ENV:variable" format. I tried variations of this (e.g. `"${ENV}:dbpass"`) as well but none seem to work.

With this, I would like to avoid creating like 10 `credentials` choices in my `parameters` section.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how the credential names can be parameterized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters) doc, in declarative pipeline the values of the parameters are available in the steps context (which implies that they are not available in any other context, eg the environment).

Instead of exposing creds with the environment directive, you can use the [`withCredentials`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#-withcredentials-%20bind%20credentials%20to%20variables) step, which allows you to assign a credentials to variables and since it's a step, you call it inside the steps context where you can also access the values of your params.

Eg:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(choices: 'Development\nStaging\nProduction', 
               description: "Select an environment to run tests against.",
               name: 'Environment')
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Run tests') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "${params.Environment}:dbpass", variable: 'DBPASS',
                                 string(credentialsId: "${params.Environment}:mqpass", variable: 'MQPASS')]) {
                        // Do stuff
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```